# has_and_belongs_to_many relationship updates not being added to changes_to_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Using Rails 6 and having trouble understanding how best to solve the issue I am having with a has_to_and_belongs_to_many relationship model not being added to the changes_to_save hash when adding or removing it from the parent model (used to create a timeline of changes).
Currently I have solved the issue creating a custom concern but I wondered if there is a better way of doing this?

edit- To clarify I want to track changes to the video, so when a video_tag is added or removed it will be included in video.changes_to_save

Example of what I have (base model)

```
class video < Base::StandardModel
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :video_tags,
      before_add:      :make_dirty,
      before_remove:   :make_dirty
...
```

Dirty Association Concern

```
module DirtyAssociationsConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :dirty_association_name
    attr_accessor :dirty_association_before_changes

    def make_dirty(record)
      if self.dirty_association_before_changes.nil?
        self.dirty_association_before_changes = self.send(association_name(record)).map(&:name).join(", ")
        self.dirty_association_name = association_name(record)
      end
    end

    def has_changes_to_save?
      dirty_association_name.present? || super
    end

    def saved_changes?
      dirty_association_name.present? || super
    end

    def changes_to_save
      dirty_association_name.present? ? build_changes.merge(super) : super
    end

    def saved_changes
      dirty_association_name.present? ? build_changes.merge(super) : super
    end

    private
      def association_name(record)
        record.class.to_s.underscore.pluralize
      end

      def association_name_ids
        "#{dirty_association_name.singularize}_ids"
      end

      def build_changes
        { association_name_ids => [dirty_association_before_changes, self.send(dirty_association_name).map(&:name).join(", ")] }
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not clear what changes you're trying to track, is it on video or on video_tag?

Comment: @Joel_Blum Sorry to be clear I want to track changes on video, so when a video tag is added it is included in the video.changes_to_save hash

Comment: changes_to_save is a hash field in video relation and you are using this to build the record with all the changes before actually saving it - is this assumption/understanding correct?

Comment: @PrasathRajasekaran yes correct, doing this to make sure that when video_tags are added/removed from the video the changes will be part of the changes_to_save hash which is part of (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html)